# How to run build on docker container in coreos?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, coreos

I have installed CoreOS as my build environment. I installed Jenkins server as a docker container in CoreOS. And I created a free style project on the Jenkins server to build my project. How can I configure the build run on docker containers on the CoreOS?

So the structure is:  CoreOS is my physical machine. Jenkins server is running in a docker container in the CoreOS. And I want to launch more docker containers to run my application. How can I achieve this? The hardest part I think is to launch a docker container in CoreOS from Jenkins JOB. I want to start a new docker container ever time for a build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but I would suggest that you take a look at the docker-machine and docker-compose utilities.

You should be able to have Jenkins use one of those to have the host start your build container.